# How to define sass variables for all scss files

Tags: sass, gulp-sass

In my project i use many scss files (more than 100 files).
The file structure is similar to the **BEM** project.

```
scss/
--block/block.scss
----/__elem/block__elem.scss
--menu/menu.scss
----/__elem/menu__elem.scss
```

and etc...
All files compiled to css files with gulp-sass plugin and concatenated to 1 css file **app.css**
The same folder i have 2 scss files.

**_variables.scss** *- for define custom variables* 
**style.scss** *- main file (i use that file to import my variables).*

```
scss/

_variables.scss

style.scss
```

In **style.scss** file contained import line with variables

```
@import "utilities/variables";
```

Yes, all variables is successful define in style.scss file, but how to define my variables for others scss files (for all scss files in folders and subfolders)?

For another files except **style.scss** in **gulp** project gives an error message:

```
out:     error sass/menu/menu.scss (Line 5: Undefined variable: "$laptop".)
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this problem.  Now i just concatenate all scss file with variables and only then connect them to the general css.
Something like this:

```
sass/**/*.scss + _variables.scss> app.scss > app.css
```